# NoClassDefFoundError in Tomcat for Abstract Class

Tags: java, class, tomcat, docker, noclassdeffounderror

I have an abstract class, `Problem`. It's package is `com.namespace.problem`. My tomcat app calls `Problem.staticMethod()` on each page. I get a 500 error, `NoClassDefFoundError` on every page. In the debugger, I can access static fields from `Problem`. I can successfully place breakpoints on its instance methods. It fails to place breakpoints on static methods and any static method I call causes a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

Tomcat is running inside a Docker container. When I run the docker container on my local machine, there are no problems. When I run it on my AWS instance, every page has a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I read that I should look for a `ClassNotFoundException` or a `ExceptionInInitializerError` but found nothing.

I cannot initialize Problem (as it is abstract). I cannot see `Problem.class` in the debugger, it causes the error as well. I can't instantiate any classes that extend `Problem`, I get the same error.

What could be causing this? The point of docker is to be platform independent so I don't know why this would happen on AWS but not my computer, I'm deploying the same WAR.

```
Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:574)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:461)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
root cause

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.namespace.problem.Problem
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:909)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:838)
    org.apache.jsp.view.system.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:381)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.namespace.problem.Problem
    com.namespace.system.Application.setInitialState(Application.java:327)
    com.namespace.system.Application.setInitialState(Application.java:296)
    com.namespace.system.Application.setInitialState(Application.java:292)
    com.namespace.mvc.controller.Controller.<init>(Controller.java:80)
    com.namespace.mvc.controller.SystemController.<init>(SystemController.java:20)
    org.apache.jsp.view.system.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:122)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
```

Comment: Is the Problem class one of your own, held inside the war at com/namespace/problem/Problem.class? Is that namespace referenced in your front end pages via an appropriate import to allow you to reference it via Problem.staticMethod()? Can you access any other object from your front end views from the same war?

Comment: @ManoDestra it's in the package. And it is imported correctly and all other classes can be accessed. I found the problem. See my answer for the stupid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there was an XML config file, whose path was defined by an env var. The var on my local machine was correct, on AWS it was wrong because someone else in my repo renamed the file. Apparently, for some reason, instead of a sensible error about the file not existing, you get a `NoClassDefFoundError` from a class that doesn't even use the config file.